# Sending POST data in C# with page redirect as in <form action="">

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, post-redirect-get

Doing some programming with POST data in C# I encountered a little problem. I need to send a form to some site (`somesite.com`) along with POST data dynamically generated. At first it was done like:

```
</form> //closing form from MasterPage
<form action="http://somesite.com" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<%=FirstNameValue%>">
    ...
    <input id="SubmitButton" type="submit">
</form>
<form id="form2"> //restoring form from the MasterPage
```

But it's rather nasty hack. Browsing through other question on the site I removed the "somesite" form and put this as a code for standard button that used to be `submit`:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.UploadValues("http://somesite.com", new NameValueCollection()
        {
            { "first_name", FirstNameValue }
        }
    });
```

It surely sends some data (I hope), but I can't test it, as `somesite.com` contains second part of the form - to be more specific, it's for sending requests to a service similar to PayPal.

Is it possible to make it work exactly as `<form action="http://somesite.com" method="POST">` form? (Clicking on `submit` will redirect you to a website with sending `POST` data?)

Comment: @Aristos - but I don't want to do this that way (from ASP), as it's more problematic in use than it seems (especially when I have to break in half the <form> tag from MasterPage)

Comment: @Aristos I want to redirect to `somesite.com` and send my POST data there from C# code, not ASP

Comment: Look at that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET

Comment: By the way, now that I look your question again, "the hack" that you say that you do, if its work, leave it. If you do not have other data that break your page, nether you make post back on the same page, then its ok.